# How to ignore URL with Node to use Backbone router without #?

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm building one page application using Backbone's router to modify browser history. I don't want to use `#` in URLs.

How to tell Node server to ignore everything in particular URL, example:

```
http://example.com/app
http://example.com/app/one/
http://example.com/app/two/
```

All these 3 URLs should point to `/app` but without redirection. Whatever user type after `/app/` should cause Node server to render staff from `/app`

Comment: What are you using to route requests in node, a framework perhaps? The answer will depend on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you are using [Express](http://expressjs.com), you would probably use wildcard patter in [routing](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing) def

```
app.get("/app/*",function(req,res){/*...*/});
```